# Can not perform action after onSaveInstanceState | AndroidPay

Tags: android, android-pay

I am using Android Pay in one of my fragments. Here is how (the relevant parts of) my fragment looks:

```
public class PaymentsFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private MaskedWallet mMaskedWallet;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Wallet.API, new Wallet.WalletOptions.Builder()
                        .setEnvironment(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_TEST : WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION)
                        .setTheme(WalletConstants.THEME_LIGHT)
                        .build())
                .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), this)
                .build();

Wallet.Payments.isReadyToPay(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<BooleanResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull BooleanResult booleanResult) {
                        if (booleanResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            if (booleanResult.getValue()) {
                                showAndroidPay();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
  }

private void showAndroidPay() {
WalletFragmentStyle walletFragmentStyle = new WalletFragmentStyle()
.setBuyButtonText(WalletFragmentStyle.BuyButtonText.LOGO_ONLY)
.setBuyButtonAppearance(WalletFragmentStyle.BuyButtonAppearance.ANDROID_PAY_LIGHT)
.setBuyButtonHeight(WalletFragmentStyle.Dimension.UNIT_DIP, 46);

  WalletFragmentOptions walletFragmentOptions = WalletFragmentOptions.newBuilder()
                .setEnvironment(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_TEST : WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION)
                .setFragmentStyle(walletFragmentStyle)
                .setTheme(WalletConstants.THEME_LIGHT)
                .setMode(WalletFragmentMode.BUY_BUTTON)
                .build();

        PaymentMethodTokenizationParameters params = null;
        if (requestMethod.getGateway().getType() == PaymentGateway.PaymentGatewayType.STRIPE) {
            params = PaymentMethodTokenizationParameters.newBuilder()
                    .setPaymentMethodTokenizationType(PaymentMethodTokenizationType.PAYMENT_GATEWAY)
                    .addParameter(GOOGLE_WALLET_GATEWAY, PaymentGateway.PaymentGatewayType.STRIPE.toString().toLowerCase())
                    .addParameter(GOOGLE_WALLET_STRIPE_KEY, ((StripePaymentGateway) requestMethod.getGateway()).getPublishableKey())
                    .addParameter(GOOGLE_WALLET_STRIPE_VERSION, com.stripe.Stripe.VERSION)
                    .build();
        } else {
            //later
        }

        MaskedWalletRequest maskedWalletRequest = MaskedWalletRequest.newBuilder()
                .setMerchantName("")
                .setPaymentMethodTokenizationParameters(params)
                .setPhoneNumberRequired(false)
                .setShippingAddressRequired(false)
                .setEstimatedTotalPrice(100.0)
                .setCurrencyCode("USD")
                .build();

        WalletFragmentInitParams initParams = WalletFragmentInitParams.newBuilder()
                .setMaskedWalletRequest(maskedWalletRequest)
                .setMaskedWalletRequestCode(LOADER_MASKED_WALLET_REQUEST_CODE)
                .build();

        SupportWalletFragment walletFragment = SupportWalletFragment.newInstance(walletFragmentOptions);
        walletFragment.initialize(initParams);

 if (walletFragment != null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.androidpay_fragment_holder, walletFragment)
                    .commit();

        }
  }
}
```

Now, when I try to rotate the device after clicking the AndroidPay button, the app crashes with exception:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState`

at the point where I am commiting in the `showAndroidPay()` method. I am aware of this [article](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html) which says that there should not be a `FragmentTransaction` commit from an asynchronous method. But in my case, I can only show the Android Pay option when I receive a success from the callback. And this is how even the [sample app](https://github.com/android-pay/androidpay-quickstart/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/wallet/BikestoreFragmentActivity.java) does it. The only difference there is that it is being done in an `Activity.onCreate()` vs `Fragment.onCreaveView()` in my case.

Any idea how can I solve this issus?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if (walletFragment != null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.androidpay_fragment_holder, walletFragment)
                    .commitAllowingStateLoss();

        }
```

Comment: yeah, I'm aware of this solution. I feel this is more of a hack.